# MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE not supported on Ubuntu 20

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

When I run this code I get "mmap: Operation not supported", according to [mmap man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)
that's because one of the flags is invalid (validated by **MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE**). The "bad" flag is **MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd_addr = open("test", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
    if (fd_addr == -1) {
        std::cout << "open: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd_addr, 100) == -1) {
        std::cout << "ftruncate: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto mem =mmap((void*)0x7f4b1618a000, 1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE | MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_LOCKED, fd_addr, 0);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        std::cout << "mmap: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Any sane ideas what that could be and how to figure out what the problem is? I use Ubuntu 20 (kernel 5.4.0-131-generic) and g++-11 (with glibc 2.31)

```
g++-11 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Replacing **MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE** with **MAP_FIXED** works just fine.
Compiling like that:

```
g++-11 -g0 -Ofast -DNDEBUG -Wall -Werror --std=c++2a -march=native -flto -fno-rtti main.cpp -pthread -lrt
```

Comment: You should just omit `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`  and check the return value to see the mapping is where you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to answer your question is to look at the source.
Taking an excerpt from [do_mmap](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/440b7895c990a63869a9d55e5c2502dd501a124e/mm/mmap.c#L1326-L1339):

```
switch (flags & MAP_TYPE) {
        case MAP_SHARED:
            /*
             * Force use of MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE with non-legacy
             * flags. E.g. MAP_SYNC is dangerous to use with
             * MAP_SHARED as you don't know which consistency model
             * you will get. We silently ignore unsupported flags
             * with MAP_SHARED to preserve backward compatibility.
             */
            flags &= LEGACY_MAP_MASK;
            fallthrough;
        case MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE:
            if (flags & ~flags_mask)
                return -EOPNOTSUPP;
```

and comparing your `flags` against those in [`LEGACY_MAP_MASK`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/cdeffe87f790dfd1baa193020411ce9a538446d7/include/linux/mman.h#L38-L54),
it becomes evident that `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` is not part of `LEGACY_MAP_MASK`, which returns the "operation not supported" error you report.

In this case, the `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` bits result in an [extra check up front](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/cdeffe87f790dfd1baa193020411ce9a538446d7/include/linux/mman.h#L38-L54) and otherwise behaves as [`MAP_FIXED`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/440b7895c990a63869a9d55e5c2502dd501a124e/mm/mmap.c#L1266-L1267).

Long story short: in this situation you can replace `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE` with `MAP_SHARED` without loss of functionality.

Doing what you suggested (`MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` to `MAP_FIXED`) has the potential of accidentally creating overlapping memory mappings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, I double checked do_mmap, just couldn't easily figure out what that LEGASY_MAP_MASK is. Anyway, do you think it is mmap bug?